# IIS 7 Application Pool work process life and Session life

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, iis-7, worker-process

In IIS7 Application Pool there is a setting Idle-time out default is 20 min,
which says:

> Amount of time(in minutes) a worker process will remain idle before it shuts down, A worker process is idle if it is not processing requests and no new requests are received.

My question is, if the worker process shut down because of the time-out time, does the session created by application which is hosted in this worker process get lost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes -- [the session data is tied to the app pool worker process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), so once the worker gets shut down, the session data is lost.

> The default behavior is to store session variables in the memory space of the ASP.NET worker process.

(Of course, this assumes you're using *InProc* as the session mode.  If you're using the database, then it will persist after the worker gets shut down.)

Comment: Could u please help review [My another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995415/why-did-not-redirect-to-view-in-asp-net-mvc-4) ? I don't know if it is related with this. thanks